# How to fix the view in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I would like to fix the view in DataGridView, not show the empty part when I focus the last row.
Like this:
[image]
Not like this:
[image]

Please any one tell me how to do. Thanks.

Comment: Well, you can change the BackgroundColor, to match the Parent's, set `BorderStyle = None`... you won't notice.

Comment: the same.  :)
I need to fix the view when I focus the last row, the default setting is that when I focus the last row, the whole grid will move up one row, and prevent the focus part not in the bottom of the entire visible area.
And I need to set the grid stay in the visible area. :)

Comment: There's no such *setting*. You can size the DGV to match a multiple of the `RowTemplate.Height` + `ColumnHeadersHeight`. You can scroll to the last row, select it and nothing scrolls anywhere (of course, unless you have Rows with different height). -- Sets the Color properties as described. `BorderStyle = FixedSingle` is not bad either.

Comment: Yes, set the larger Height value can be a solution, thanks. :)

Comment: On the "big list of things you have to fix before you can ship your app" this must be in the bottom 1%, surely..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the larger Height value can be a solution.
Like this,
[image]